# How to add the value 0 at the beginning of each multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 52 weeks array's and each week array has a sub array with 9 values.
now I need to add a value 0 at the begin of each array and every next week I need 1 value more.

For example (notice that the 0-8 will be in a for loop)

```
    $vruchtzettings_week["week1"][0-8] = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
    $vruchtzettings_week["week2"][0-8] = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
    $vruchtzettings_week["week3"][0-8] = 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
    $vruchtzettings_week["week4"][0-8] = 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
```

Comment: I saw that, but i want to change the index keys

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_unshift()`](https://www.php.net/array_unshift), like this

```
$week=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
array_unshift($week,0); //[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Comment: Hey i dont get this to work....

Comment: what's your problem? its perfect